# Computing the transformation matrix that took place between two quadrilaterals

Tags: matrix, graphics, linear-algebra, transformation

I have two sets of 4 vertices that make a quadrilateral in 2D coordinate space. These 4 vertices can be scaled, rotated, translated, and skewed in any way. For example:

[image]

With my limited knowledge of linear algebra I'm assuming that a "transformation matrix" can be used to create a mapping between vertices in State 1 and vertices in State 2.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I have several quadrilaterals in one state (possibly different quads), that all undergo some uniform transformation (camera movement) to get to state 2. I'm assuming that if I compute the transformation from one quad in state 1 to state 2, I can apply the same transformation to all quads in state 1.

Comment: Yes, there is one.  It would combine a rigid body translation and a strain matrix relative to some coordinate system to calculate deformations.    If the coordinate system is the original one, the large strain tensor is Green-Lagrance; if relative to the final one, it's the Euler strain tensor.

Comment: Thank you, I have some reading to do then. What do you mean by the coordinate system being original or relative? Both coordinate systems will be upon a 2D camera frame

Comment: I meant a coordinate system relative to the polygon at the start of the deformation and another at the end.  You'll have to read about continuum mechanics and strain tensors.

Comment: You want to [find the corresponding homography](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog).